# Using a stored procedure to import data from MS Sql to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am importing data into an application that uses MySQL. The data is coming from MS SQL. Because the table names change every month in the MS SQL db we are using a stored procedure to concatenate the table name in addition to getting data from other tables.

The problem is that it seems we are losing the PK identifier on the MS SQL side so my MySQL database won't take the data. Should we be using a view instead? Is there a way to retain the PK identity in a stored procedure. Thanks.

Here's a better explanation of my problem:
1. Host database table name change each month (YYYYMMtablename)
2. Need to select columns from two tables
3. The foreign DB (MySQL) needs a query like SELECT a,b,c,d,from tablename
4. I am not able to alter the way my application works, although I can make changes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the identity value in an insert statement on both SQL Server and MySQL.

> MySQL allows you inserting identity values explicitly, so you actually do not need IDENTITY_INSERT option, or in other words it is always set in MySQL. 
>   [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,499281,503603)

For MS SQL Server, please read the [SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The stored procedure needs to bring the pk info over so my db will accept it. I am unable to alter the java code that is used to import the data into my (MySql) db. Thanks though.

Comment: you just need to add that column to the select statement that retrieves the data and use the value in your insert. If you cannot select the column, then you need mystic magical powers to guess the values ;)

Comment: Ricardo, the column that is the pk is in the stored procedure. But because of the data manipulation (also retrieving info from another table) it seems that the  pk column is not retaining its identity as a pk.

Comment: i think that the problem here is the way you state the question. I thin that by "is not retaining its identity as a pk" you mean that you expect that the target table should have that column as a PK? that has nothing to do with the data. You just need to change the attribute of the table itself. modify the tart table and set the PK to be that column. or; The destination table does not exist, and is created by the stored procedure? Then include an ALTER statement after creating the target table and set the PK attribute.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)

Comment: To be clear: a primary key is NOT an identity. That is a different attribute. primary key is a constraint.

Comment: Ricardo, thank you for assisting me. The issue is that one of the columns I am importing via the stored procedure is a pk. The column in the db that i am importing into is also a pk. MySql is telling me that the data from the MS Sql column is NOT a pk.

Comment: Please provide the error message. Because PK is not a thing in the data, it is a control attribute in the table managed by the server. The data itself is no different to say an integer, or a string.